# Jmeter problems redirect

Tags: jmeter

Hello I'm using JMeter for testing an application but before trying any complex test plan I decided to try a simple request.

My test plan is like this:

Sampler --> HTTP Request
   Name: redirect test
   Server Name or IP: localhost/sample
   Method: GET
   Path: redir.php

My redir.php has this code `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=here.php">`

And my here.php file contains this text : `HELLO, YOU HAVE BEEN REDIRECTED`

After that, I create a `Response assertion` that searchs for the word 'HELLO'.

When I execute the plan and check the results in the `View Results Tree` listener it says an error ocurred because the word 'HELLO' was not found.

This image shows my HTTP Request configuration

http://s7.postimg.org/k19tw7p0r/http_Request.png

And this one the Assert:

http://s4.postimg.org/4dg2sebfh/htpp.png

And this is the error JMeter returns to me

http://s8.postimg.org/dxbl00wv9/error_fdfdf.png

I have been searching and I found this in the response data section:

http://s9.postimg.org/h49m8ippr/redirect.png

Looks like Jmeter is searching the string 'HOLA' in the  response.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter is not a browser so will not interpret an HTML page containing:

> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=here.php" />

So assertion fails because this page does not contain "Hello".

So to make your sample work, you need to extract from the previous response "here.php" , make JMeter call it and then check the Hello word in this latter response.

To do so add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) under the first request and extract the url

Then add a Http Request to call this URL and add your assertion there.

Comment: Damn... Thought the option 'Follow redirects' will "follow" all the app redirects. Thank you for your help Ubik